# OOP: Assign to variable a method

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to assign to a variable in a method, another method ( as a function ).

So maybe in the method "A" I want to assign the method "B" as function.

I tried this, but the var_dump is false and the parameter $fn is treated as string ( I think ).

```
<?php
class MyClass {

    public function call( $fn ) {
        var_dump( is_callable( $this->$fn ) );
    }

    public function required( $str ) {
        return empty( $str );
    }

}

$class = new MyClass;
$class->call( 'required' );
```

Comment: I would suggest creating a seperate class for a method or group of methods you want to store as a variable. Then simply just instatiate that class into a variable. Much neater and easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a better method for going about this but I think this is sort of what you're after:

```
class MyClass
{
    public function call($function, $parameters = null)
    {
        if (method_exists(__CLASS__, $function)) {
            return $this->{$function}($parameters);
        }
    }

    public function required($string) 
    {
        return empty($string);
    }
}

$class = new MyClass;
var_dump($class->call('required', 'yo'));
```

Not entirely use why you want to do this, and I imagine there is probably a better method of achieving your end goal but the above should at least meet your requirement. It is limited it how it handles parameters but it's a starting point.